# Calculate the proportion of a column in relation to the total count

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to do something real simple but it's not working whatever I do. I'm trying to calculate the proportion of records where `'Device Cost'<5000` from the total count. I have:

```sql
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM lab1_equipment
WHERE Device Cost < 5000
```

But I'm not sure how to make this the denominator and use `COUNT (*)` with no where clause as the numerator. I don't need it grouped, just a single proportion. Any help would really help. Thanks!

Data Sample:

[image: Data Sample]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a conditional aggregation as below:

```
SELECT AVG(case when Device Cost < 5000 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) 
FROM lab1_equipment
```

or

```
SELECT count(case when Device Cost < 5000 then 1 end) / count(*)
FROM lab1_equipment
```